# js slideUp doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add slideUp effect to my page. My `<body>` code is:

```
<script>
        $('#slide_up').click(function(){
         $('p.text_study').slideUp('slow', function() {
          $('#result').html("ok");
         });
        });
</script>
<img src="img/slide_up.png" alt="slide_up" id="slide_up">
<p class="text_study">Some text.</p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

When i click a button nothing happens. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in `$(document).ready`. Your click handler is being assigned before the `#slide_up` element is ready for use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide_up').click(function(){
     $('p.text_study').slideUp('slow', function() {
      $('#result').html("ok");
     });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Also i forget to add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` in `<head>`

Answer (score 1):

JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/3uhCa/2/

Nothing wrong with your code. are you loading jquery correctly?

```
<img src="img/slide_up.png" alt="slide_up" id="slide_up">
<p class="text_study">Some text.</p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not functionally the same as OP's code because the fiddle executes the code onload. In the fiddle, if you change it to "<head> no wrap", then you'll get the same result as OP.